# Is Poochyena's Fang move locked to your starter

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Is the Poochyena's from the hidden pokemon tutorial elemental fang locked to your starter? i.e. Treecko-pickers will always get ThunderFang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the tutorial Poochyena will have an elemental Fang move corresponding to your starter.

- Treecko - Thunder Fang
- Torchic - Ice Fang
- Mudkip - Fire Fang

This allows Poochyena to cover certain weaknesses of your starter. Thunder Fang is super-effective against Flying types, Ice Fang is super-effective against Ground types, and Fire Fang is super-effective against Grass types.

Comment: Ice isn't SE against rock... and [citation needed]

Comment: My mistake about type weaknesses, I always confuse Ice and Water when it comes to which one's 4x effective against Rock/Ground types. As for [tag:citation-needed], you're not going to find one outside of sites like [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/792673-pokemon-omega-ruby/70633805).